# MySQL update query ideas for all records

Tags: mysql, multiple-records

I am trying to achieve an SQL Query that updates all the records from day 13 in a table as follows:

```
UPDATE
    some_table 
SET
    'col3' = 'col2value',
    'col2' = 'col1value',
    'col1' = 'aNewCustomValue'
WHERE
    day = '13';
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

In short for each record the value from col3 must become the value from col2, col2 must get the value from col1 and col1 will receive a new custom value.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by the best way ?

Comment: Well, anything that will work for now will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE
    some_table
SET
    col3 = col2,
    col2 = col1,
    col1 = 'aNewCustomValue'
WHERE
    day = '13';
```

or to be safe if cols have "unsafe" names:

```
UPDATE
    `some_table`
SET
    `col3` = `col2`,
    `col2` = `col1`,
    `col1` = 'aNewCustomValue'
WHERE
    `day` = '13';
```